# $sce.trustAsHtml and ng-show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

http://codepen.io/pondnetic/pen/qdxGVV

I have a javascript string of a few lines of html displayed in my ionic app with

```
<div ng-bind-html="strVar | to_trusted"></div>
```

to_trusted is a simple filter using $sce

```
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}])
```

As shown in the codepen, ng-show and ng-hide do not function when displaying html this way. How can I get this to function as intended?

Comment: Not detailed enough for an answer, but angular is basically not taking your HTML as template, but as raw HTML. You should see into how to dynamically load templates.

Comment: As Alpha said, you're adding HTML that isn't being compiled.  This is something you'd do in a directive, not a controller.

Comment: I'd say in this case identifying the error and pointing in the right direction is definitely enough to warrant an answer, @Alpha.

Comment: "Sure, @Jan." (Sorry, had to take the chance.) In all seriousness, I just wrote a detailed answer, you can see why I didn't think it'd fit into a comment. Thanks for the encouragement -- it was the very first reason I started writing the answer. =)

Comment: Wow, way overkill, good job. I think since the solution is so far outside the scope of the question, pointing in the right direction would've been enough to warrant an answer though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current problem that you're experiencing is that Angular is taking your text as HTML correct, as you wanted to, but after doing so, it does not bind to the new attributes and classes as if it were an Angular template.

This behavior is not a deficiency in Angular's design, but rather a prevention that a particular directive could not turn the site completely unresponsive. Think if it needed to reevaluate each new piece of generated HTML for new directives and bindings, it would very likely enter into a never ending loop of execution and checking.

**Do not use dynamic templates**

The first approach to solving your problem is changing the approach: do not use dynamic templates. It is very likely that the reason you want to do that is to allow for user input to generate the template (which becomes a security concern, a potential entry for XSS), or that a third party system is generating the HTML for you, which is also a bad idea because of the separation of concerns from the systems (if your system is supposed to generate the HTML, it should not mix up other sources, much less trust them).

**Use directives**

If the reason you're into inserting HTML is for the purpose of reusing the HTML, what you may be looking for are *directives*, an Angular component that allows you to do exactly that: reuse and isolate behavior that is very tightly coupled to the generated HTML.

Here's a quick example from the [directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

**Dynamic templating**

If you really want to go into dynamic templating, there's a way to do it. You would create a directive in the very same way as the example above, but rather than hardcoding the template into the directive (or into a template file), you can dynamically feed the contents of the template into the `link` function and compile it yourself with the scope provided, like so:

```js
angular.module('variableDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.customer1 = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
    $scope.customer2 = {
      name: 'Joseph',
      address: '123 Fake St'
    };
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function($compile) {
    var getTemplate = function(attrs) {
      var isVip = attrs.type === "vip";
      return isVip
        ? "(VIP) Name: {{customer.name}} -- (VIP address hidden)"
        : "Name: {{customer.name}} -- Address: {{customer.address}}"
    };
  
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var template = getTemplate(attrs);
      element.html(template);
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
  
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: linker,
      scope: {
        customer: '=info'
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="variableDirective">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <my-customer type="regular" info="customer1"></my-customer>
    <br />
    <my-customer type="vip" info="customer2"></my-customer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note however this is necessary because the compilation of the template happens after the directive has been instantiated, so you don't get access to the scope or the attributes at the moment of the directive definition.

A more detailed explanation and a reusable approach (the one I based my example on) you can find here: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/